# Does having a large method name increase latency?

Tags: java

Do longer method names have an increased latency when called? Is this a noticeable effect after a long period of calls?

Comment: No. Method names are not processed when the jvm is executing the bytecode.

Comment: If the length of your methods is the only bottleneck of your application then you can say that you don't have any performance issues :-)

Comment: And as some people say: performance is a luxury problem anyway. (If your customers are complaining about bad performance; that basically means: you have customers that bought your product and are using it. Much better than having a greatly-performing product that was never shipped because you ran out of money before you could start selling it ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, method names have nothing to do with performance. And btw, the JVM doesn't use name the name to invoke the method, it uses it symbolic link, which point to the method name in the constant pool.

```
invokestatic  #2 //Method fn:()V
```

So even the `byte-code` doesn't get bloated with lengthy method names.

Answer (score 0):

No. The length of the method name doesn't make a difference.

The fact that you're using a method does, though. More the methods, more the overhead. That's the price we pay for cleaner and more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it: be careful when diving into "performance" from this "microscopic" point of view.

Of course it is a good thing to understand the effects of using different approaches in your source code (to avoid "stupid mistakes").

But efficiency and performance is something that receives "too much priority" too often. Typically, when you focus on creating a clean, maintainable design, the outcome will have "good enough performance". If not; well a clean, maintainable design is easier to change than a messed-up design anyway.

Keep in mind:

*"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." and I agree with this. Its usually not worth spending a lot of time micro-optimizing code before its obvious where the performance bottlenecks are. But, conversely, when designing software at a system level, performance issues should always be considered from the beginning. A good software developer will do this automatically, having developed a feel for where performance issues will cause problems. An inexperienced developer will not bother, misguidedly believing that a bit of fine tuning at a later stage will fix any problems."*

*What Hoare and Knuth are really saying is that software engineers should worry about other issues (such as good algorithm design and good implementations of those algorithms) before they worry about micro-optimizations such as how many CPU cycles a particular statement consumes.*

from [here](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)